# Fatal Error in Android program

Tags: android, cordova

Basically i created a web application and now i am going to convert this web application to android app using phonegap but i am getting this error.

**CrudActivity.Java**

```
 package com.crud.crudappone;

    import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;

    import android.os.Bundle;


    public class CrudActivity extends DroidGap {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
        }

    }
```

**manifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.crud.crudappone"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="8"
            android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

       <supports-screens 
        android:largeScreens="true" 
        android:normalScreens="true" 
        android:smallScreens="true" 
        android:resizeable="true" 
        android:anyDensity="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
        <application
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <activity
                android:name="com.crud.crupappone.CrudActivity"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_main" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize">

                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

**Logcat:**

```
07-23 14:44:59.698: E/AndroidRuntime(662): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-23 14:44:59.698: E/AndroidRuntime(662): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.crud.crudappone/com.crud.crupappone.CrudActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.crud.crupappone.CrudActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.crud.crudappone-2.apk]
07-23 14:44:59.698: E/AndroidRuntime(662):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1569)
07-23 14:44:59.698: E/AndroidRuntime(662):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
07-23 14:44:59.698: E/AndroidRuntime(662):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
07-23 14:44:59.698: E/AndroidRuntime(662):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
07-23 14:44:59.698: E/AndroidRuntime(662):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-23 14:44:59.698: E/AndroidRuntime(662):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
07-23 14:44:59.698: E/AndroidRuntime(662):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
07-23 14:44:59.698: E/AndroidRuntime(662):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-23 14:44:59.698: E/AndroidRuntime(662):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-23 14:44:59.698: E/AndroidRuntime(662):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
07-23 14:44:59.698: E/AndroidRuntime(662):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
07-23 14:44:59.698: E/AndroidRuntime(662):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-23 14:44:59.698: E/AndroidRuntime(662): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.crud.crupappone.CrudActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.crud.crudappone-2.apk]
07-23 14:44:59.698: E/AndroidRuntime(662):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
07-23 14:44:59.698: E/AndroidRuntime(662):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
07-23 14:44:59.698: E/AndroidRuntime(662):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
07-23 14:44:59.698: E/AndroidRuntime(662):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
07-23 14:44:59.698: E/AndroidRuntime(662):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1561)
07-23 14:44:59.698: E/AndroidRuntime(662):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: Can you post the code of your main class (`CrudActivity`) and also your manifest?

Comment: Initialize your class in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: can anyone tell me first how to add my code here. i would like to show  the code here but i dnt knw how to add

Comment: @swathi click on edit and add your code..

Comment: @swathi the same way as you posted your logcat.Click edit and post

Comment: @swathi Just paste your code and select it and click on code sample (The button with curly braces **{}**) And please do add the logcat errors along with code :)

Comment: i just followed this link and did this project "http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.1/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just replace:**

```
android:name="com.crud.crupappone.CrudActivity"
```

to

```
android:name="com.crud.crudappone.CrudActivity"
```

in your manifest file inside activity tag, and then see the magic.

Comment: what is the difference?

Comment: hey i don't know what i have to modify. please tell me clearly. @Robi kumar Tomar

Comment: just replace crupappone by crudappone in your package, the only difference of p & d in it. repeating again read it carefully.

Comment: yup i have changed it.but i am getting the same error and i didnt understand what is this error line why it is calling as Lcom/crud                                 "07-24 13:21:50.471: W/dalvikvm(372): Link of class 'Lcom/crud/crudappone/CrudActivity;' failed "

Comment: hey i got it, but it is showing like the requested url is not found.